# HTML blow section is not formatted properly as many line gaps i can see

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below html which is actually embeded in xsl itself as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                Hello,
                <br>
                </br>
                <br>
                </br>
                Please be advised of the following details
                    <font color="black" face="Arial" size="2" >
                    <br>
                        <br>

                            <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap">Invoice Id</td>

                                </tr>
                                <xsl:for-each select="brokermail/invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><xsl:value-of select="InvoiceId" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <TR>

                                </TR>
                            </table>
                        </br>
                    </br>
                    <p>
                        <br>
                        </br>
                                Please note that this is a system generated email.
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                    For any queries, please direct your mail to our group email -
                                    rety@csss.com.
                                    </br>
                                    </br>

    <br>                                
<br>Thanks &amp; Regards,</br>
<br>ASE rage,</br>
<br>WER TYU UHTR &amp; Markets,</br>
<br>14 2rd Main Road, uae ,</br>
ERT, RTYU, 440044, uae
<br>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</br>
</br>                                   
</p>
                </font>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now in the above html specially after  "Thanks & Regards," section every thing is printed in a separate line but there is more space as shown below ...

```
Thanks & Regards,

ASE rage,

WER TYU UHTR & Markets,

14 2rd Main Road, uae,
ERT, RTYU, 440044, uae
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but i want the thing to be printed as now please advise in the html what changes I have to do to achieve this thing

```
Thanks & Regards,
ASE rage,
WER TYU UHTR & Markets,
14 2rd Main Road, uae,ERT, RTYU, 440044, uae
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have the below html which is actually embeded in xsl itself as shown
>   below

Actually, what you have is an XSLT stylesheet. The "embedded" HTML is just a template for the HTML code that's supposed to be returned as the result of the transformation. And it was written by someone who doesn't know what they're doing.

More specifically, you have `<br>` elements with content in them. A `<br>` element must be empty. What you see is the result of a browser interpreting **both** the start-tag and the end-tag of a `<br>` element as a line break.

You need to place a **single, self-closing, `<br/>` tag** (or an **empty** `<br></br>` pair of tags) wherever you want a line break, and eliminate **all** the existing `<br></br>` tag pairs that have any content in them.

Comment: Thanks can you pls do the necessary changes in above post itself that will help to grasp more Thanks in advance

Comment: @ndsfdddsfd I believe I have been clear enough. If not, you can always ask for a clarification - but I am not here to do your work for you.